# Alsa : loop with dmix

Tags: alsa

I'm using snd-aloop to record currently played sound.
I'm able to play a sound, hear it and record it. 
But I've lost software mixing feature : I cannot anymore play multiple sounds at a time.

Here is my working configuration with sound play and record (no mixing) :

```
pcm.multi {
    type route;
    slave.pcm {
        type multi;
        slaves.a.pcm "output";
        slaves.b.pcm "loopin";
        slaves.a.channels 2;
        slaves.b.channels 2;
        bindings.0.slave a;
        bindings.0.channel 0;
        bindings.1.slave a;
        bindings.1.channel 1;
        bindings.2.slave b;
        bindings.2.channel 0;
        bindings.3.slave b;
        bindings.3.channel 1;
    }

    ttable.0.0 1;
    ttable.1.1 1;
    ttable.0.2 1;
    ttable.1.3 1;
}

pcm.!default {
        type plug
        hint.description "default with sound loop"
        slave.pcm "multi"
}

pcm.output {
        type hw
        card 0
}

pcm.loopin {
        type plug
        slave.pcm "hw:1,0,0"
}

pcm.loopout {
        type plug
        slave.pcm "hw:1,1,0"
}
```

I've tried different configurations  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/194547/how-can-i-use-alsa-dmix-and-multi-plugins-together

I've tested with this config :

```
pcm.snd_card { # my usual sound card
    type hw
    card 0
}

ctl.!default { # default control; alsamixer and such will use this
    type hw
    card 0
}

# software mixer for sound card
pcm.dmixer {
    type dmix
    ipc_key 1024
    ipc_perm 0666 # allow other users
    slave.pcm "snd_card"
    slave {
        period_time 0
        period_size 1024
        buffer_size 4096
        channels 2 # must match bindings
    }
    bindings {
        0 0
        1 1
    }
}

# software mixer for loopback device
pcm.dmixerloop {
    type dmix
    ipc_key 2048
    ipc_perm 0666 # allow other users
    slave.pcm "hw:1,0,0"
    slave {
        period_time 0
        period_size 1024
        buffer_size 4096
        channels 2 # must match bindings
    }
    bindings {
        0 0
        1 1
    }
}


pcm.!default {
    type plug
  hint.description "default with sound loop"
    slave.pcm "out"
}

# Multi, splitting onto usual card and loopback
pcm.out {
    type plug
    slave.pcm {
        type multi
        slaves {
            a { channels 2 pcm "dmixer" }
            b { channels 2 pcm "dmixerloop" }
        }
        bindings {
            0 { slave a channel 0 }
            1 { slave a channel 1 }
            2 { slave b channel 0 }
            3 { slave b channel 1 }
        }
    }
    ttable [
        [ 1 0 1 0 ]   # left  -> a.left,  b.left
        [ 0 1 0 1 ]   # right -> a.right, b.right
    ]
}
```

Here is result of commands using different pcms :

```
aplay -D default /tmp/test.wav
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1109:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
aplay: main:788: erreur à l'ouverture audio: Argument invalide
> :( $ aplay -D dmixer /tmp/test.wav
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1109:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
aplay: main:788: erreur à l'ouverture audio: Argument invalide
> :( $ aplay -D snd_card /tmp/test.wav
Lecture WAVE '/tmp/test.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Fréquence 48000 Hz, Stéréo
```

From these tests, I do not understant several points :

- I cannot open "dmixer" pcm slave i.e. "snd_card", but I can play a
  sound using "snd_card". Why doesn't "dmixer" pcm open its slave?
- I can play several sounds using pcm "snd_card"    ( I call at a same
  time several  `aplay -D snd_card /tmp/test.wav` )    and I hear a mix
  of sounds. Where is software mixing done? when I    play on
  "snd_card" dmix plugin is not used

How can I have software mixing and loopback?

Comment: Do you get the same error when playing directly to the `output` device?

Comment: I've done some tests with config given in a post that has been solved with your help http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/194547/how-can-i-use-alsa-dmix-and-multi-plugins-together but strangely I have an error when playing on default device (I've updated my post)

Comment: Try removing the period/buffer parameters.

Comment: I tried, removing these parameters, I get same result.

Comment: More info about my config can be found here : http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=dd05a274b420f57e28805bfa81fcdb0cd54359b7

Comment: When I run speaker-test : it stays stuck.

Comment: Root cause seems to be dmix on raspberry, I asked some help here : https://archlinuxarm.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=65&t=11317